# Get UIInterfaceOrientation when just one is supported

Tags: ipad, uiinterfaceorientation, device-orientation, uideviceorientation

I have an iPad App that supports just one orientation (landscapeRight). Unless I want to get the current orientation of the device to display something if the device is held the wrong way.

How can I do this? I tried like 6 different methods of determining the orientation. But all of them just determine the interface orientation, not the device orientation.

Thanks for advice, with kind regards, Julian